# problem with a remote server scp

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path

I have admin access to a remote computer with Debian linux. At first everything were working well. I tried to define some variables globally so that all users can run a specific code. Now I can't scp files to that server. when i run scp command it says:

```
bash: scp: command not found
lost connection
```

`scp` is available both in my locale pc and on the server. I can connect to the remote computer using ssh. but when I connect it says:

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

but when I run this command:

```
which id
```

the output is:

```
/usr/bin/id
```

And I think the path to basic codes is defined for the system. Also the remote computer knows the pass to scp and the output to `which scp` is:

```
/usr/bin/scp
```

All I remember about what I did is to create a file in `/etc/profile.d` and afterwards I deleted that file. I also checked and became sure that there is no wrong PATH specifications in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile`.

Does anybody know whats wrong with the remote computer?

Comment: Something is wrong with your shell variables. Try `echo $PATH`, `which scp`, `ls -l /usr/bin/scp`, and `env`. Post the results!

Comment: The `$PATH` on the remote machine is obviously wrong under some circumstances. You have either not restored the changes you've made, or you've deleted the default shell initialization files that used to set up `$PATH`.

Comment: Please also post the syntax of your `scp` command

Comment: output of: `echo $PATH` in remote computer:
`.:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/mostafa/documents/scripts/executables:/usr/local/bin/g09`

Comment: output of: `which scp` in remote computer:
`/usr/bin/scp`

Comment: output of: `ls -l /usr/bin/scp` in remote computer:
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 88208 Jul 15  2019 /usr/bin/scp`

Comment: first lines of output of: `env` in remote computer:
`LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34: ...
SSH_CONNECTION=172.17.13.131 50213 172.21.176.59 22
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
OLDPWD=/etc
XDG_SESSION_ID=240
USER=mostafa
PWD=/home/mostafa
HOME=/home/mostafa
SSH_CLIENT=172.17.13.131 50213 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
MAIL=/var/mail/mostafa
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=mostafa
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1002/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1002`

Comment: remaining lines of output of: `env` in remote computer:
`PATH=.:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/mostafa/documents/scripts/executables:/usr/local/bin/g09
_=/usr/bin/env`

Comment: I want to mention additionally that when I create a new user on the remote computer, this problem exist for it. I mean scp is not  possible, and when I ssh to that user says:
 `-bash: id: command not found
-bash: [: : integer expression expected`
(also ssh access is possible)

Comment: syntax of my scp command:
`scp myfile mostafa@172.21.176.59:`

Comment: @MostafaTavakoli You should really add all the information from comments section into your question directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I was added a wrong PATH definition in `/etc/environment`.
correcting that mistake solved the problem.

Comment: This answer is not only confusing, but worse than that, it does not explain anything at all.

Comment: Never mentioned `/etc/environment` in the original question. Answer does not discuss what went wrong and what corrections you made. Adds no value to the community.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following below command to check whether the user has access to `scp` command or not:

```
echo $PATH
```

Example output:

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

This will display commands paths in which user have access.

Suppose if you are checking for `scp` command, `scp` command will be located in `/usr/bin/`. If the output of `echo $PATH` doesn't contain `/usr/bin/` then it displays message "command not found".

To fix the issue execute

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/
```

For permanent changes add the above to your `.bash_profile`

Comment: Kindky update the reason for downvote

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I checked these before post the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your `.bashrc` file. Use the following command to restore the default version and then reconnect.

```
$ cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Comment: I tried this before posting the question. It doesn't resolve the problem.